# how to use default id from mongodb in react list

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

i have got the id from mongodb in my browser
i am using the name but i cant use the id
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03U97.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivr8C.png

Comment: Can you share some code snippets or snapshot of your response? If you are getting mongo id inside the response or not.

Comment: @ShubhamWaje i put some images i have got the id from mongodb in my browser i am using the name but i cant use the id

Comment: So are you getting runtime error (breaking your application while accessing _id) or just a compile time error inside the IDE?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje only run time error and my app working properly but the vscode telling me the id does not exsit

Comment: I think you should add `_id: string` inside the `ICountry` interface. That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eslint, then the rule `no-underscore-dangle` is most probably active. This rule disallow using the underscore. So you can use following eslint instruction before your line to allow the variable `_id`:

```
/*eslint no-underscore-dangle: ["error", { "allow": ["_id"] }]*/
```

Reference: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-underscore-dangle